# Update submodule after rewriting commit history

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

So here's what you need to know:

- Repo A was a large legacy repo used in several other projects as a submodule on GitHub Enterprise.
- While migrating Repo A to GitLab, we found that some commits deep in the history had their data corrupted and were causing the migration to fail.
- In order to remove these corrupted files, we had to rewrite the git history around the corrupted commit.
- Repo B uses Repo A as a submodule.

I have been attempting to update Repo B by doing the following:

1. Clone Repo B from GitLab
2. Update the path in .gitmodules to point to the new (GitLab) location of Repo A
3. `git submodule init`
4. Confirm that Repo A's url is correct and pointing to the new (GitLab) Repo A
5. `cd repo-b/repo-a`
6. `git checkout $hash` where `$hash` is the exact same commit in Repo A that we used to point to, but with the new hash because history was rewritten.

I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 01b517847508dd5942887950e4a5ab1468bb21b4
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, [every answer I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797720/3906760) seems to imply that I *should* be able to checkout a specific hash in the submodule and then commit that change to the repo.

Also, just for clarification, I *did* confirm that my hash is correct and exists by checking it out in the new (GitLab) Repo A, so it's there.

Comment: Make sure that when you check out commits in repo B (the one that uses A as a submodule) you are *not* using "recursive" checkout. That is, you want to get the commit from the superproject, with its wrong submodule hash ID. You can then use this commit to build a new *superproject* commit in which the hash ID is updated in place. Basically, you must now rewrite repository B so that it uses the new hash IDs for each gitlink (for which you need the map of "old A commit to new A commit" from the conversion of A).

Comment: Once you've built a new B superproject repo, *then* recursive checkout from the new rebuilt B should work. Until then you're stuck with labor-intensive manual non-recursive superproject checkouts followed by careful submodule checkouts by hash ID done "by hand".

Comment: It does sound like you're in this process, so I think maybe what's going wrong is that B has already cloned the "wrong" A instead of the "right" A and is now stubbornly using the old A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I can't explain *why* it works, but it fix the error.

I had previously tried this with a `git submodule update` between step 3 and step 5, and that didn't seem to work. However:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update --checkout
```

Did in fact allow the hash checkout to succeed in the submodule.